# Upgrade from 16.04 LTS ONLY to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, lts

I have an Ubuntu VM running 16.04 LTS. I plan to shut it down, take a snapshot and then try an in-place upgrade to 18.04. Is there an argument to "do-release-upgrade" to upgrade to that specific version ?
Thanks,
Bill

Comment: No, it doesn't need arguments but it needs a special procedure because 16.04 has been out of standard support since 2019!! If it was me I would just backup personaal files and install fresh a new VM with the current 22.04. Ubuntu 18.04 has less than a year of support left therefore wasting lots of time to upgrade to it is a dumb move.

Comment: possibly it will still work normally, since 16.04 has not reached EOL yet, and is still in ESM (so it's *possible*, but not *guaranteed*, that the sources are still around and accessible even without ESM). "do-release-upgrade" should take you directly to the next LTS version by default, if you installed a LTS version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the EOL dates.  Do you know of issues going from 16.04 to 22.04 ?   I have a different VM at 18.04, which I'll upgrade to 22.04.

Comment: The command `do-release-upgrade` will take you to the *next* release only. Or, in your circumstance, the next LTS release only. Any other method of changing releases is untested and not supported. For a lengthy list of known release-upgrade issues, read the release notes for the new release.

Comment: Have you enabled ESM support?   Depending on where you are in the world, and where your network traffic travels during the upgrade, you may find upgrade easy, or impossible.  Your location may require updated certificates that are only downloadable for *xenial* if ESM is enabled (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) as there have been made updates since 16.04 ended *standard support* back in 2021-April.

Comment: The upgrade tools would only update 16.04 to either 16.10 being the next release (*that option closed when 16.10 reached EOL long ago now in 2017*) OR the next LTS with 18.04 still possible but that's *supported* now only if ESM is *enabled* (*though it does still work depending on your network location and what certificates have expired on your box; ie. when it's run matters with more expiring as time passes*)